# How do I use this Google Apps Script?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-apps-script

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_range.html#getFormula

Is there a script I can install or do I need to write my own? After that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to write a google-apps-script that calls that method, is you want to use it.

In your spreadsheet go to Tools->Scripts->Scripts Editor and write your code there.

Of course, the `getFormula` method simply returns a String representation of the formula in the given cell. Something you can do by just moving the cursor over to that cell. So you don't need to write a script for that.